# ImportError: No Module named 'driver'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a voice program with Python 3, like given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31257805/760393

But I keep getting errors: 
..\site-packages\pyttsx\engine.py, line 18, in  import driver..

Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/0DEV/L X/voice2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .engine import Engine
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\engine.py", line 18, in <module>
    import driver
ImportError: No module named 'driver'
```

Comment: Please, give full traceback

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It's a mistake in calling `driver.py` file in `engine.py`.
You must edit engine file and at calling section change this:

`import driver`

to:

`from . import driver`